# Uninstall is still running after installer exits

Tags: nsis

I am not sure how to put this here, I will do my best. Please help me out

I have a patch installer, which installs and uninstalls as expected. But after uninstalling the patch from program files, I have tried uninstall other software. All I got a pop message saying that let the uninstall finish uninstalling.

All I figured out is at the end of uninstalling my patch, I am starting a process by executing .exe file. My uninstaller waits for that process to quit, which I do not want to quit.

Other option I have is to force the user to reboot after uninstalling the patch, which I do not wish to do.

I tried Exec, ExecDos, and ExecCmd with /ASYNC, but I still see the same problem.

Try 1

```
ExecShell open "$INSTDIR\system\teven.exe"
```

Try 2

```
ExecDos::exec /NOUNLOAD /ASYNC "$INSTDIR\system\teven.exe" ""
Pop $0
ExecDos::isdone /NOUNLOAD $0
```

Can anyone help me to solve this. How can I start teven.exe and left it running and make my uninstaller not waiting teven.exe to quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have to force the uninstaller to wait if you are going to do other things after the uninstaller completes. When you uninstall from Add/Remove programs Windows even forces a wait for all your child processes started by the uninstaller...

Why are you using /ASYNC if you want to wait? (Edit: I guess you don't want to wait?) `ExecDos::isdone` does not wait, it just checks, use `ExecDos::wait` if you want to wait.

If you are not using advanced options and don't need stdin input then you don't really need to use 3rd-party plugins:

If teven is a console application and you want to hide the console window (and wait):

```
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\system\teven.exe"'
```

otherwise:

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\system\teven.exe"'
```

If you actually don't want to wait you can just use `Exec` but Windows might force a wait anyway when uninstalling...

Comment: Ohoo!! I am unaware of that if uninstall from Add/Remove, window forces to wait. Is there any way to start a process as separate instead as child process, so that Add/Remove thinks that uninstallation is finished

Comment: No not really, it is by design to fix some old (InstallShield?) uninstallers. There is http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Escape_ARP_Job_With_New_Process but I don't know if it works on every version of Windows...